# SDO_JOIN on different subqueries from one table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, geometry, spatial

I want to make spatial join on one table, but different subqueries from it. Table has geometry in column named "geometry".
I have tried following, but with no success:

```
select *
from

TABLE(SDO_JOIN('query1', 'geometry',
                      'query2', 'geometry',
                      'mask=ANYINTERACT')) c,
(select * from table1 where  orig is not null) query1,
(select * from table2 where  orig is  null) query2
```

How can I join two tables, based on intersection?
And I want to extend this query to find only those from first table, which have intersection with more than one object from second table. How this can be achieved?

Comment: You received error `ORA-13249:  Error in join: check spatial table/indexes`? 
I suspect Oracle has to _see_ specific spatial indices. In docs I've seen only **tables** mentioned in `from` clause. Probably `select * from
         table(sdo_join('table1', 'geometry','table2', 'geometry','mask=ANYINTERACT')) c,
         table1, table2 
  where table1.orig is not null and table2.orig is null` is what you are looking for? I did not work with spatial data, but this syntax worked for examples I imagined.